# Selecting column containing XML into FOR XML query

Tags: xml, t-sql, for-xml

I have a temporary table that has a column 'Header' that contains XML, that looks something like this:

```
<Header>
    <RecordID>Value</RecordID>
    <CompanyCode>Value</CompanyCode>
</Header>
```

I am then selecting that temp table column into a FOR XML query, that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
    Header
FROM
    #TempTable
FOR XML PATH ('Asn'), ROOT ('Ans'), ELEMENTS
```

However, this doubles up the header node, and results in an XML that looks like this:

```
<Ans>
  <Asn>
    <Header>&lt;Header&gt;&lt;RecordID&gt;value&lt;/RecordID&gt;&lt;CompanyCode&gt;value&lt;/CompanyCode&gt;&lt;&lt;/Header&gt;</Header>
  </Asn>
</Asns>
```

How can I stop the header tag from doubling up when I select it into my XML query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the elements that are subelements of the Header element. Use the [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type) method on the XML value to do that.

Depending on how you're set up, you can select without a column name to remove the Header element generated from the column name (see the second query).

```sql
DECLARE @x XML='<Header>
    <RecordID>Value</RecordID>
    <CompanyCode>Value</CompanyCode>
</Header>';

DECLARE @t TABLE(Header XML);
INSERT INTO @t(Header)VALUES(@x);

SELECT
    Header.query('Header')
FROM
    @t
FOR XML PATH ('Asn'), ROOT ('Ans'), ELEMENTS ;

-- Alternatively, without query, depending on how you're set up
SELECT
    (SELECT Header)
FROM
    @t
FOR XML PATH ('Asn'), ROOT ('Ans'), ELEMENTS ;
```